# .NET Regular Expression white space special characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

This pattern is not working sometimes (it works only for the 3rd instance).  The pattern is  `^\s*flood\s{55}\s+\w+`

I am new to regular expression and I am trying to write a regular expression that captures all the following conditions:

```
Example 1: flood                 a)
Example 2: flood                 As respects
Example 3: flood                 USD100,000
```

(it's in a tabular format and there's a lot of space between flood and the next word)

Comment: Why not [`^\s*flood\s+(.*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cs*flood%5cs%2b%28.*%29&i=flood+++++++++++++++++a%29%0d%0aflood+++++++++++++++++As+respects%0d%0aflood+++++++++++++++++USD100%2c000&o=m)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is saying:

`^\s*`  The start of the string may have zero or more whitespace characters

`flood` followed by the string `flood`

`\s{55}` followed by exactly 55 whitespace characters

`\s+\w+` followed by one or more whitespace characters and then one or more word characters.

If you want a minimum number of whitespace characters, say at least 30, followed by one or more word chraracters, then you could do this:

`^\s*flood\s{30,}\w+`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string input =
@" flood                 a)
   flood                 As respects
   flood                 USD100,000";
string pattern = @"^\s*flood\s+.+$";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are a lot of spaces between flood and the next word you could omit `\s{55}` which is a quantifier that matches a [whitespace character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) 55 times.

That would leave you with `^\s*flood\s+\w+` which does not yet match all the values at the end because `\w` matches a word character but not a whitespace or any of `),`.

To match your values you might use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and add the characters that you allow to match:

[`^\s*flood\s+[\w,) ]+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cs*flood%5cs%2b%5b%5cw%2c%29+%5d%2b&i=+flood+++++++++++++++++a%29%0d%0a+flood+++++++++++++++++As+respects%0d%0a+flood+++++++++++++++++USD100%2c000&o=m)

Or if you want to match any character you could use a dot instead of a character class.

According to your comment, you might use a positive lookbehind:

[`(?<=\(13\. Deductible\))\s*(\s*flood\s+[\w,) ]+)+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%2813%5c.+Deductible%5c%29%29%5cs*%28%5cs*flood%5cs%2b%5b%5cw%2c%29+%5d%2b%29%2b&i=+Limits+section+%0d%0aflood+++++++++++++++++a%29%0d%0a+flood+++++++++++++++++As+respects%0d%0a+flood+++++++++++++++++USD100%2c000%0d%0a%0d%0a+%2813.+Deductible%29%0d%0a%0d%0aflood+++++++++++++++++a%29%0d%0a+flood+++++++++++++++++As+respects%0d%0a+flood+++++++++++++++++USD100%2c000%0d%0a%0d%0a+Limits+section+%0d%0aflood+++++++++++++++++a%29%0d%0a+flood+++++++++++++++++As+respects%0d%0a+flood+++++++++++++++++USD100%2c000%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0atest&o=m)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/XGY35899)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I should have defined my problem better. I need to extract flood information from two different sections within the same document.Since RegEx captures the 1st instance of the match it finds I am capturing the flood information from the Limits section(which appears 1st). I want the regular expression to go to the right section (13. Deductible) and then capture the flood information from there. How can I write the correct formula. This doesn't seem to help  [0-9]{1,3}.\WDEDUCTIBLES(.*\n)+?flood

Comment: @user9872456 I have added an update to my answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: [0-9]{1,3}[.]\s+DEDUCTIBLES.*(\r\n.*)*^flood

Comment: ^\s*\w+[.]\s+DEDUCTIBLES.*(\r\n.*)*^\s*flood seems to work on a notepad editor using regular text, however when I use against the actual text in pdf it doesn't. looks like it has to with pdf formatting. Example Text: 12. DEDUCTIBLES test the regular expression out
This regular expression is being written for deductible section in a pdf
until it finally reaches the required row within the deductibles table There are a lot of text between deductible and flood
flood                   USD50000000

Comment: @user9872456 You could try [`^\s*\w+[.]\s+DEDUCTIBLES[\s\S]+?((?:^\s*flood.*(?:\r?\n|\r)?)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/7F2ggq/1) and use the first capturing group.

Comment: For c# try  [`(?<=^\s*\w+[.]\s+DEDUCTIBLES[\s\S]+?)(\s*flood\s+[\w,) ]+)+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5cs*%5cw%2b%5b.%5d%5cs%2bDEDUCTIBLES%5b%5cs%5cS%5d%2b%3f%29%28%5cs*flood%5cs%2b%5b%5cw%2c%29+%5d%2b%29%2b&i=1.+LIMITS+test%0d%0atest+test+%0d%0aflood+++++++++++++++++++USD50000000%0d%0a%0d%0a12.+DEDUCTIBLES+test+the+regular+expression+out%0d%0aThis+regular+expression+is+being+written+for+deductible+section+in+a+pdf%0d%0a+flood+++++++++++++++++a%29%0d%0a+flood+++++++++++++++++As+respects%0d%0a+flood+++++++++++++++++USD100%2c000%0d%0aflood+++++++++++++++++++USD50000000&o=m)

Comment: [`^\s*\w+[.]\s+DEDUCTIBLES.*(\r\n.*)*^*(\s*)flood`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cs*%5cw%2b%5b.%5d%5cs%2bDEDUCTIBLES.*%28%5cr%5cn.*%29*%5e*%28%5cs*%29flood&i=12.+DEDUCTIBLES+test+the+regular+expression+out%0d%0aSince+this+regular+expression+is+being+written+for+a+pdf+it+has+a+table+with+lots+of+rows+until+it+finally+reaches+the+required+row+in+within+the+deductibles+table+%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++++flood+++++++++++++++++++USD50000000%0d%0a)